# Erro ao obter hora com row.getCell()

Tags: java, string, apache, datetime, apache-poi

Estou obtendo dados a partir de uma planilha no excel.

```
public void Hora()
    Cell horaAgen = null;

    if(row.getCell(7) != null ){
        horaAgen = row.getCell(7);
        System.out.println("hora: "+horaAgen);
   }

}
```

Na planilha esta: 9:00:00
Apos ser lido obtenho: 31-dez-1899

Quais funções devo utilizar para obter a hora correto.

**Observação:**

1. a data consigo obter corretamente dd/mm/yyyy
2. estou utilizando o apache poi
3. Qual o formato de dados que está sendo utilizado na tabela: Time
4. Devo converter o a hora obtida para string

Comment: Faltam informações na pergunta. Qual o tipo de variável está sendo usada? Qual o formato de dados que está sendo utilizado na tabela? Talvez esse artigo possa ajudar: http://blog.alura.com.br/como-converter-string-para-date-em-java/

Comment: Qual o tipo de variável está sendo usada: Cell

Comment: Qual o formato de dados que está sendo utilizado na tabela: time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para este problema foi essa:

```
public void obterHora(){
    String hora;
    int h=row.getCell(7).getDateCellValue().getHours();
    int m=row.getCell(7).getDateCellValue().getMinutes();
    int s=row.getCell(7).getDateCellValue().getSeconds();

    hora = h+":"+m+":"+s;

    SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date data = formatador.parse(horario);
    horaAgen = new Time(data.getTime());

    System.out.println("hora: "+horaAgen);
}
```

Resultado:

> 9:00:00 
>   12:00:00

sempre no formato

> HH:mm:ss

Dessa forma atendeu as minhas necessidades